# Operating Micropython-running WeMos D1 mini (ESP8266) pins with HTTP requests

Tags: http, esp8266, micropython

What I am trying to ultimately achieve is to control my garage door opener with a relay connected to a WeMos D1 Mini, connected to my home WiFi. I am using the `openGarageDoor()` function. Everything works fine with serial connection.

I have been trying to run HTTP server on a WeMos D1 Mini with [this script](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/examples/network/http_server.py).

```
    customertagsAction() -- try:
    import usocket as socket
except:
    import socket


CONTENT = b"""\
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Hello #%d from MicroPython!
"""

def main(micropython_optimize=False):
    s = socket.socket()

    # Binding to all interfaces - server will be accessible to other hosts!
    ai = socket.getaddrinfo("0.0.0.0", 8080)
    print("Bind address info:", ai)
    addr = ai[0][-1]

    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(addr)
    s.listen(5)
    print("Listening, connect your browser to http://<this_host>:8080/")

    counter = 0
    while True:
        res = s.accept()
        client_sock = res[0]
        client_addr = res[1]
        print("Client address:", client_addr)
        print("Client socket:", client_sock)

        if not micropython_optimize:
            # To read line-oriented protocol (like HTTP) from a socket (and
            # avoid short read problem), it must be wrapped in a stream (aka
            # file-like) object. That's how you do it in CPython:
            client_stream = client_sock.makefile("rwb")
        else:
            # .. but MicroPython socket objects support stream interface
            # directly, so calling .makefile() method is not required. If
            # you develop application which will run only on MicroPython,
            # especially on a resource-constrained embedded device, you
            # may take this shortcut to save resources.
            client_stream = client_sock

        print("Request:")
        req = client_stream.readline()
        print(req)
        while True:
            h = client_stream.readline()
            if h == b"" or h == b"\r\n":
                break
            print(h)
        client_stream.write(CONTENT % counter)

        client_stream.close()
        if not micropython_optimize:
            client_sock.close()
        counter += 1
        print()


main()
```

The requests are received properly and the GET variables are shown on the print(). The best i have been able to do is

```
req = client_stream.readline()
    print(req)
    while True:
        h = client_stream.readline()
        if h == b"" or h == b"\r\n":
            break
        print(h)
    client_stream.write(CONTENT % counter)
    //my function here:
    if 'opengaragedoor=1' in req:
        openGarageDoor()
    client_stream.close()
```

I don't know how to parse the request properly. I only have come up with this dirty solution. This probably causes a timeout on the requesting system, as Postman or such needs to wait for the function to run through.